# .change does not work when element is bound to another?

Tags: jquery

Not quite sure how to explain this but here goes.

I have a function which hides/shows based on a checkbox:

**$("#checkbox").change(change_visibility);**

```
  function change_visibility() {
   if ($("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
       $("#theForm").fadeTo("opacity", "1", function() {
        //End Animation
     });

     } else {
       $("#theForm").fadeTo("opacity", "0.3", function() {
         //End Animation
     });
   }
```

Problem is that now I have bound this checkbox to a button elsewhere and change() is not behaving as I would expect.

```
   $("#myButton").click(function(){
      $("#checkbox").attr("checked", true);
   });
```

Even though the checkbox is changing, as it should, it doesnt seem to be calling the change_visibility() function as it does when I click on it manually.

Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you change the status or value of an input element, the change event is not triggered.

But you can trigger it manually:

```
$("#checkbox").prop("checked", true).change();
```

Comment: Wow super fast thank you so much! I have seen this change() attached to the end before and never knew what that was all about. Now I know. =)

Comment: Huh answered so fast I actually have to wait to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to do this

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
      $("#checkbox").attr("checked", true);
      $("#checkbox").change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the .change() event doesn't get fired when you change the checkbox manually. But the solution is still very simple. Just call the change_visibility() function yourself:

```
  $("#myButton").click(function(){
      $("#checkbox").attr("checked", true);
      changeVisibility();
  });
```

Comment: You know I actually tried this and it did not work either, it didnt even call the function. Any idea why this would not work???

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event handler to `change` event and call the change method on button click.

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
   if (this.checked) {
       $("#theForm").fadeTo("opacity", "1", function() {
        //End Animation
     });

     } else {
       $("#theForm").fadeTo("opacity", "0.3", function() {
         //End Animation
     });
   });


 $("#checkbox").attr("checked", true).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
      $("#checkbox").attr("checked", true).trigger('change');
});
```

That should trigger the change event after you dynamically check the box.